# LaTex fails to break long line in lstlisting

Tags: listings, line-breaking, verbatim

I have this sample tex file which has a line with a very long word in it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    escapechar=@
}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    bookmarksopen=false,
    bookmarksopenlevel=1,
    colorlinks=true,
    pdfstartview=Fit,
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
    pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight
}


\title{My Title}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newpage

\section{First Section}

\begin{lstlisting}
This is a long line that should  haveBeenBrokenAtAnAppropriatePositionWhichDefinetlyExistsButStillFailedToBreakProperly

haveBeenBrokenAtAnAppropriatePositionWhichDefinetlyExistsButStillFailedToBreakProperly
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Although I am using `breaklines` in my `lstlisting` the line in question does not break. The long word can definetly fit in a line of its own, as can be seen in the final PDF file.

[image: Failed to break long line]

Is there a way to fix this **without** allowing to break within a word?

**Update**

As requested in the comments I added `\listfiles` and this is the output:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
listings.sty    2002/04/01 1.0 (Carsten Heinz)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
lstpatch.sty    2002/10/13 1.0i (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2002/04/01 1.0 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2015/06/04 1.6 listings configuration
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   color.sty    2016/01/03 v1.1b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
  sample.out
  sample.out
 ***********
```

I also uploaded all involved files here:

http://www96.zippyshare.com/v/QUOffLqF/file.html

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example produces a line break on my machine. What TeX distribution are you running?

Comment: @egreg I am using `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16` on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I'm running the exact same version of pdfTeX on Ubuntu, and your MWE doesn't produce the screenshot you have posted. Instead, I get, as expected, a linebreak. Furthermore, I see that in your solution you use a different documentclass than in your question. Can you update either the answer or the question, so that (1) the MWE actually reproduces your problem, and that (2) your solution matches your question?

Comment: Can you double-check that if you copy the example from your question into a new `.tex` file, and run `pdflatex` on it, then you get the output that is in your question?

Comment: @Tiuri Strange. I compiled and ran it multiple times and it never broke the line. Maybe it is one of the underlying libs? Anyway, I changed the documentclass so that I can choose a smaller font. I updated the answer to better reflect that.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yes, I double-checked and the result is still the same. I even opened it with different pdfviewers.

Comment: @Tiuri Also note that the long word appears twice. I also put it on a second line to demonstrate that it does fit on a line of its own. The first line is the one that should break but does not.

Comment: TeX is supposed to give identical results on all other machines, so this is something rather serious. Could you add `\listfiles` to your file (anywhere before `\begin{document}`) and paste the output into the question?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Done. See my update.

Comment: Compared to running on my computer: your `listings.sty` and `lstmisc.sty` are from 2002 and there's even a `lstpatch.sty` (also from 2002) that isn't present today, but your `listings.cfg` is from 2015. I guess this was an issue (bug) in the listings package that was fixed sometime before 2014 (here's a list of [announcements](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/listings)); you can try upgrading your `listings` package and see if it fixes itself.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thank you very much. Updating to a newer version of listings.sty solved the problem. Could post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? This is, after all, the real solution. My answer is just a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posting from comment at request of OP…)*

This appears to be a bug in an ancient version of the `listings` package. The output of `\listfiles` shown in the question indicates that `listings.sty` and `lstmisc.sty` being used were from 2002, along with a `lstpatch.sty` that appears to be no longer used today. The `listings` package has had [many versions](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/listings) since then, and the more recent versions don't have this bug.

Upgrading the `listings` package fixes the issue.

Comment: (Ideally we should find out exactly what the bug was and when it was fixed… I took a look through the announcements but it isn't mentioned AFAICT, so one would have to look at the code.)